# How to build and run a .NET Core Console app in Docker which contains multiple libs?

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core, dockerfile

I'm struggling to find a good example of doing this, so hoping for some help.

My project/file structure is like this:

```
\src
\src\BulkImporter
    \src\BulkImporter\BulkImporter.csproj
\src\lib1
    \src\lib1\lib1.csproj
\src\lib2
    \src\lib2\lib2.csproj
```

So, i'm trying to dockerize `BulkImporter`. To build the app, it needs `lib1` and `lib2`.

I'm trying to do a multi-stage docker build, so a build + runtime image.

Here's my current Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# copy everything and build the project
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet restore src/BulkImporter/*.csproj
RUN dotnet publish src/BulkImporter/*.csproj -c Release -o out

# build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/src/BulkImporter/out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "BulkImporter.dll"]
```

But, it doesn't seem right. I don't know if i need to 'build everything'. Also, i'm got a `csv` file in my app, that is erroring when i run the app, as it's looking in an `app/Data/mycsv.csv`, when normally it exists in `/Data/mycsv.csv`.

So i think there's some problems with my Dockerfile.

Can someone point me to a good example of how to do this, or tell me what's wrong with my Dockerfile?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I've updated my Dockerfile to be closely based on the [dotnet docker example](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/samples/dotnetapp/Dockerfile).

It's building fine, but still facing the CSV issue.

Here's my updated dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY src/BulkImporter/BulkImporter.csproj ./BulkImporter/
COPY src/Domain/Domain.csproj ./Domain/
COPY src/ElasticSearch.SearchService/ElasticSearch.SearchService.csproj ./ElasticSearch.SearchService/
WORKDIR /app/BulkImporter
RUN dotnet restore

# copy and publish app and libraries
WORKDIR /app/
COPY src/BulkImporter/. ./BulkImporter/
COPY src/Domain/. ./Domain/
COPY src/ElasticSearch.SearchService/. ./ElasticSearch.SearchService/
WORKDIR /app/BulkImporter
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# build final release runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/BulkImporter/out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "BulkImporter.dll"]
```

I'm building the image from the folder above the `src` folder, with the following command:

> docker build -t bulkimporter . -f .\src\BulkImporter\Dockerfile

The error i get when running is:

`Could not find file '/app/FakeData\locations.csv'.`

Yet when i do a `dotnet publish` from the `BulkImporter` folder on my PC, the `bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\publish\FakeData` folder has the `locations.csv` file there.

The code that loads the CSV is this:

```
var suburbLines = (await File.ReadAllLinesAsync("FakeData\\locations.csv")).Skip(1);
```

(runs fine outside Docker).

Can anyone spot the problem?

Comment: Can you add the code that loads the .csv file? How are you getting the directory/path to read the file from?

Comment: Can you add the exact errors? Also, "But, it doesn't seem right." doesn't add much information. Can you add more exact details?

Comment: @SimplyGed updated

Comment: @omajid updated. "But it doesnt seem right" was in reference to the fact i needed to 'copy everything', when i shouldn't need to. But, i solved that with the dotnet sample one. So the only problem remaining is reading the CSV.